# strcontain not returning message in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to do something like if this person name matches a list of blacklisted people warn the user saying "This person is blacklisted". So I decided to use strcontain but I am having some difficulty using it where nothing is being return.

```
  <?php  
  use App\blacklist;
$userName = $user->Name;
$userName = strtoupper($userName);
//dd(userName) --> return Tom, originally was Tom

$blacklist = blacklist::select('blacklist_name')->get();
//dd($blacklist) --> return TOM

  if($contains = str_contains($userName, [$blacklist])){
      echo "This person is blacklisted";
    }
  ?>
```

Where am I doing wrong here, can somebody help me with this problem? Thanks a lot

Inside blacklist table contain blacklist name like this:
TOM, JACK, JERRY

Comment: str_contain is not a function in PHP. But strpos() is or in_array() You also should turn on Errors.

Comment: can you share the response result of this query? 
`$blacklist = blacklist::select('blacklist_name')->get();`

Comment: @Qazi the result is shown in the question where it return TOM

Comment: @halojoy but strpos return me the position of the string if I am not wrong right? I want to use a function similar to LIKE in the sql statement

Comment: Is it case sensitive? If so your need to lowercase them both, so if case matters then dont use the function.

Comment: what your be the case, if you have multiple records in database? share the response array

Comment: `if (str_contains(strtolower($userName), strtolower($blacklist))){`

Comment: I already change all of them to uppercase already @LawrenceCherone with the use of strtoupper

Comment: use it like this

`blacklist::select(.....)->where('blacklist_name','LIKE','"%$userName%"')->get()`

Comment: @Qazi in the array i have something like this TOM, JACK, JERRY. So I want to make it like if the name i have now contain any of the following, echo message

Comment: @Qazi I tried doing that and it return the message but the message is shown in all the other user even though their name is not inside the blacklist, example John, which is not under the list but it is still being shown the message

Comment: thats why I am asking for, to share with me your query complete obj/array result, So I can know that how your data comes

Comment: The helper function is using [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) in a loop so if you pass it an array it only needs match 1 for it to be true, also strpos is case sensitive. See source: [str_contains()](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/609920b0d028ce898bf10bc0a58a887908b3299a/laravel/helpers.php#L347)

Comment: @Qazi updated question, so is that what you meant?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone is it possible for you to give an example on how to use it? Sorry I am quite unsure of how to properly use it

Comment: you mean, you are having single column, and in which you are keeping comma separated values? right ?

Comment: @Qazi they are an array, and are all in a single column but with different rows

Comment: can you share the database screen shot that how your keeping the records in DB table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$blacklist = blacklist::select('blacklist_name')->get();
```

return a collection object in laravel ORM. So try this

```
$collection = blacklist::select('blacklist_name')->get()->toArray();
$blacklist = array_column($collection,'blacklist_name');
if($contains = in_array($userName, $blacklist)){
  echo "This person is blacklisted";
}
```